# Publishing Asp.Net Core project to web hosting website from VS2019 - not sure how to go ahead

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, web-hosting, publishing

I've built an Asp.net Core web application that i want to upload to https://misshosting.se/. I've tried to publish via FTP https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aKR3.jpg but all i get is a white page with the files that i've uploaded https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ1y4.jpg .

What i'm wondering is if there's a specific way to upload an asp.net core web app or perhaps if the hosting site has to support an asp.net core web app. I've published to azure before which went great, but i've never tried something like this.

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, i've just never done this before and i'm not sure what to do. I'd be really grateful to get some help with this and hopefully learn a thing or two. Thanks

Comment: Is your host a IIS or Linux? Do they support .NET Core? What version is your app and what version do they support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `Miss Hosting` does not accept hosting ASP.NET projects.

You can look over [Microsoft's website](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/hosting) if you want to see a list websites which allows you to host asp.net.